# Probability of the gap between two adjacent values of a random sample

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose we have $N$ i.i.d. random variables, $X_i$, drawn from a pdf $p_X(x)$.
I want to find the pdf of the gap $s$ between any two adjacent random variables.

There are $N(N-1)$ ways to choose two variables ($X_i$ and $X_j$) to be in "position" $x$ and $(x+s)$ and these happen with probability $p(x)p(x+s)$. Then, the remaining $N-2$ variables need not to be lie in between, and this happen with probability $\left(F(x)+1-F(x+s)\right)^{N-2}$, where $F(x)$ are the c.d.f. of $p(x)$.

So, integrating over $x$:

$$
p(s)=N(N-1)\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(x)p(x+s)\left(F(x)+1-F(x+s)\right)^{N-2}dx
$$

BUT, if we check the normalisation, i.e. we calculate the integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}p(s)ds
$$

we find $N-1$ and not 1, as it as it should be.

So, the true pdf of $s$ should be $p(s)$ dived by $N-1$.

I do not understand why this is the case.

Thanks

Comment: You want a gap of exactly $s$?  If these are continuous random variables, that probability would be $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for pointing it out. What I mean is a gap between $s$ and $s+ds$, so with $p(s)$ I mean a pdf.

Comment: Your definition of "gap" isn't well-defined here. For any realization of $N$ i.i.d random variables, you actually have $N-1$ gaps appearing. For example, suppose $N=4$ and $X_1 = 2,X_2 = 1, X_3 = 5, X_4 = 9$. Then by your definition, this outputs gaps of $1,3$ and 4. I suspect this is where the extra factor of $N-1$ is coming in.

Comment: @forgottenarrow You are right! Maybe that’s the problem!

Comment: It is not really clear to me what the event you want to calculate the probability of actually is. Consider, for clarity, the CDF of your random variable $s$, and call it $F_S(s)$. Then you want to compute $F_S(s) = \mbox{P}\{S<s\}$. But what is $S$? The maximum gap among the $N-1$ gaps? The mimimum gap?

Comment: Yes, now I'm confused too. The definition of the gap is not clear. Thanks